# How can I make the size of my feature image smaller (not file size) on my shop page (the page that has all of the products listed)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I would like to make the picture of my product on my shop page (the page that has all of my products) smaller - not smaller in file size smaller in size in relation to my text. Using wordpress woocommerce storefront

Comment: This can be easily accomplished with CSS, just set the `height` / `width` property to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: You can register custom image size and use that image size where ever you want.

Comment: Yes but where? That is where I am having the trouble.